# Public member 'get_Range' on type 'Worksheet' not found

Tags: .net, excel, office-interop

I am trying to use the code in below link. It is throwing the above exception at

```
Dim aRange As Range = ws.get_Range("C1", "C7")
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Excel sheet is opening.

I tried two different versions of DLL when referencing V12 and V14. Both throws the same error. How to resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: The code in the link you provided doesn't have `Dim`?

Answer (score 0):

Range is a dynamic object and the compiler cannot check the methods and properties which leads to above runtime exception. From my C# experience you just need to use ws.Range instead of get_Range. Can you try that?